# Split sentence by words with regex in R

Tags: regex, r, split

I'm using (or I'd like to use) R to extract some information. I have the following sentence and I'd like to split. In the end, I'd like to extract only the number 24.

Here's what I have:

```
doc <- "Hits  1 - 10 from 24"
```

And I want to extract the number "24". I know how to extract the number once I can reduce the sentence in "Hits 1 - 10 from" and "24". I tried using this:

```
n_docs <- unlist(str_split(key_n_docs, ".\\from"))[1]
```

But this leaves me with: "Hits  1 - 10"
Obviously the split works somehow, but I'm interested in the part after "from" not the one before. All the help is appreciated!

Comment: ``n_docs <- sapply(strsplit(key_n_docs, "from"),`[`,2)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract from a single character string:

```
strsplit(key_n_docs, "from")[[1]][2]
```

or the equivalent expression used by @BastiM (sorry I saw your answer after I submitted mine)

```
unlist(strsplit(key_n_docs, "from"))[2]
```

If you want to extract from a vector of character strings:

```
sapply(strsplit(key_n_docs, "from"),`[`, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually the result of `str_split` would contain the number you're searching for at index `1`, but since you wrap it with `unlist` it seems you have to increment the index by one. Using

```
unlist(strsplit("Hits  1 - 10 from 24", "from"))[2]
```

works like a charm for me.

[demo @ ideone](http://ideone.com/NtcSfh)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
numbers <- str_extract(doc, "[0-9]+$")
```

This will give only the numbers in the end of the sentence.

```
numbers
"24"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to extract the number:

```
sub(".*from *(\\d+).*", "\\1", doc)
# [1] "24"
```